# How to prove these claims about ideal sheaves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation

The following claims come from the proof of Proposition 3.10 (Page 66) of D.Huybrechts' *Fourier-Mukai Transforms in Algebraic Geometry*. Since I couldn't find these results in Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* and I have no idea how to prove them, I hope someone can give me the details about these claims.

Let $X$ be a Noetherian scheme.

- **Claim 1**. If
  $\mathcal{O}_X=\mathcal{F_1^\bullet}\oplus\mathcal{F_2^\bullet}$, we
  assume that $\mathcal{F_1^\bullet}$ and $\mathcal{F_2^\bullet}$ are
  coherent sheaves, for their cohomology is concentrated in degree
  zero (Maybe we can just assume $\mathcal{F_1^\bullet}=\mathcal{F_1}$, $\mathcal{F_2^\bullet}=\mathcal{F_2}$). Then they are ideal sheaves of certain closed subschemes, say:
  $X_j\subset X$, $\mathcal{F_j^\bullet}\simeq \mathcal{I}_{X_{j}}$
  ($j=1,2$).
- **Claim 2**. $\mathcal{I}_{X_{1}}+\mathcal{I}_{X_{2}}\subset
     \mathcal{I}_{X_{1}\cap X_{2}} $
- **Claim 3**. $\mathcal{I}_{X_{1}\cup  X_{2}}\subset \mathcal{I}_{X_{1}}\cap \mathcal{I}_{X_{2}}$ and
  $\mathcal{I}_{X_{1}}\cap \mathcal{I}_{X_{2}}=0$

For Claim 1, my thoughts as follows: Since $\mathcal{O}_X=\mathcal{F_1^\bullet}\oplus\mathcal{F_2^\bullet}$, we have an exact sequence

$$0\longrightarrow \mathcal{F_1^\bullet} \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{F_1^\bullet}=\mathcal{F_2^\bullet} \longrightarrow 0.$$

So, for any open subset of $U$ of $X$,

$$0\longrightarrow \mathcal{F_1^\bullet}(U) \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(U) \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(U)/\mathcal{F_1^\bullet}(U) \longrightarrow 0.$$

is an exact sequence of $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$-modules. Hence $\mathcal{F_1^\bullet}$ is a coherent sheaf of ideal on $X$. By Proposition II 5.9 on Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* (Page 116), $\mathcal{F_1^\bullet}$ is the ideal sheaf of a closed subscheme. **But I am not sure it is correct**.

Comment: 2 and 3: Really no idea? You know the definition of $I_A$?

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg，it's the kernel of the closed immersion, but I don't know how to see it with $X_1\cap X_2$ and $X_1\cup X_2$. By the way, what is the union and intersection of two schemes?

Comment: The intersection $X_1\cap X_2$ should be interpreted as the fibered product $X_1\times_X X_2$, where the maps employed are the closed immersions $X_i\hookrightarrow X$. For the union, think about (just set-theoretically) the fact that if $f|_{X_1} \equiv 0$ and $g|_{X_2}\equiv 0$, then $fg|_{X_1\cup X_2}\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 0):

For **claim 1**, apply first exercise 2.31 to replace $\mathcal{F}_{i}^{\bullet}$ by a complex with a single coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}_{i}$ in degree 0. Then we have $\mathcal{O}_X \cong \mathcal{F}_{1} \oplus \mathcal{F}_2$. In particular this means that each canonical map $\mathcal{F}_i \to \mathcal{O}_X$ allows us to identify $\mathcal{F}_i$ with a *subsheaf* of $\mathcal{O}_X$, thus an ideal sheaf. Now use a well-known correspondence between quasicoherent ideal sheaves and closed subschemes.

**Claims 2** and the first equality of **claim 3** follow from, say, an affine-local argument (and glueing by sheaf axioms). The last equality follows from the fact that the sum is direct (similar to standard linear algebra for direct sum decompositions).